# Can i implement extreme design elements in my app with Visual Studio, or do i need Blend?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, expression-blend

I'm new to Visual Studio and Blend and i'm trying to see their difference. I thought that Blend was ideal for adding more design and interactivity into your app so i chose to use this in order to create an app about a virtual museum (which i wanted to include design and 3d elements).

So far i have created **2 Grids**. The **1st Grid** contains a sign in or sign up option(along with its design for which i used Blend tools). The **2nd Grid** is the registation form which i wanted the user to be redirected to after the user has clicked the sign up button. I'm trying to make the transition from grid 1 to grid 2 like if i had two windows forms, but i can't seem to find how i can do that. Any ideas on how to do it?
I tried to open it into Visual studio and it doesn't seem to respond that well.I suppose i must do something wrong.

So taken the previous difficulties, i'm wondering whether Blend is not necessary to use to create this kind of app and i could simply use standard Visual Studio's windows form without having problem adding design elements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Blend is good for creating animations, but the XAML that it produces otherwise is not great. I would use Visual Studio and learn how to write XAML code without using a drag-drop style designer. There are open source transition controls out there all ready to go. Don't make it yourself if it already exists.

Comment: Also keep in mind you can set up dummy classes or even XML files with hard-coded data that VisualStudio will use to help visualize your interfaces; both will be stripped from the builds themselves.

Comment: Well i want to include animations too, can i work the animations on Blend and then import-merge them into my Visual Studio WPF?

Comment: Anyone who says Blend isn't useful for custom high end designing...doesn't do it. The Storyboard frame recorder alone saves TONS of time making higher end animations. However, if you want to have any real success, learn the XAML in depth, in my opinion I love working with XAML a lot more than HTML/CSS stuff and I do both on a daily basis. I'll often have the same solution open in both VS and Blend and just save/swap between the two based on what I'm working on. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has all that you need to be able to do your interfaces as you want them to be. As Glen Thomas said, you should learn how to code in xaml to create your interface. Visual studio gives you a render of what it looks like in real-time while coding it so it might be helpful to do it this way.